# Java Excel Poi file could cannot open as attachement in gmail

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hi would like some ideas on this matter if anyone knows how.

Am using a java program to update an excel file with additional data.
Then i use java mail to send this excel file to some people.

The problem is they cant open the file online unless they download it.

When i open the file before i send it, sometimes it asks for changes to be saved sometimes its not. If i do a manual modification and save the file then it opens in attachments online.

My question is how i can pro grammatically modify the excel file and be able to opened by google when i send it.

Thank you

Comment: if someone has a small working example to compare with my code or a solution would be doing me a big favor. Thanks

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: This aint a pure code request. My program is too big to post here. Maybe someone else has a similar problem and might share his opinion.